# How to add a section title to boxed content on Wordpress homepage

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on the redevelopment of my page Thoughtforce.org and I like that it says "latest posts" on top of the main content, and I'm trying to replicate it on Wordpress twentysixteen theme. It appears as though they've added a  tag to do this, but I'm not sure, and I've searched for hours. Here is what the  tag looks like.

```
<div id="main" class="site-main boxed group">
<div id="primary" class="content-area boxed">
                    <h3 class="section-title"><span>Latest Posts</span></h3>


    <div id="content" class="site-content group one-column" role="main"                 

<article id="post-455" class="boxed post-455 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-sociology">
            <a href="http://www.thoughtforce.org/de-facto-vs-de-jure/" title="De Facto vs. De Jure (And Their Relationship to Segregation)" class="home-thumb boxed">
        <img width="435" height="247" src="http://www.thoughtforce.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/waiting-room-435x247.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="">
```

Also, I believe the solution is somehow tied to the 's identification with the class "section-title". Here's where I think that code matters.

```
 .section-title, #reply-title{
    font-family:'Raleway', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#dc2834;
    margin-left:-35px;
    padding-left:35px;
    padding:2px 0 1px 35px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position:relative;
}
    .section-title a{
    color:#fff;
}
    .section-title:before, #reply-title:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:-5px;
}
    .section-title:after, #reply-title:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
    background:#dc2834;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
```

Lastly, the code for twentysixteen in that area looks like this:

```
    <div id="content" class="site-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">




<article id="post-1" class="post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized">
    <header class="entry-header">
```

And I've added the box. This was the code:

```
 #main {
    padding:30px;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

}
```

***edit*** Added code:

```
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area boxed">
        <?php upright_breadcrumb(); ?>

        <h3 class="section-title"><span>
                <?php
                if ( is_category() ) {
                    printf( __( 'Category: %s', 'upright' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );

                } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
                    printf( __( 'Tag: %s', 'upright' ), '<span>' . single_tag_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );

                } elseif ( is_author() ) {
                    /* Queue the first post, that way we know
                     * what author we're dealing with (if that is the case).
                    */
                    the_post();
                    printf( __( 'Author: %s', 'upright' ), '<span class="vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( "ID" ) ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_author() ) . '" rel="me">' . get_the_author() . '</a></span>' );
                    /* Since we called the_post() above, we need to
                     * rewind the loop back to the beginning that way
                     * we can run the loop properly, in full.
                     */
                    rewind_posts();

                } elseif ( is_day() ) {
                    printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'upright' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' );

                } elseif ( is_month() ) {
                    printf( __( 'Archives: %s', 'upright' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'F Y' ) . '</span>' );

                } elseif ( is_year() ) {
                    printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'upright' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'Y' ) . '</span>' );

                } else {
                    _e( 'Archives', 'upright' );

                }
                ?>
            </span></h3>
```

Comment: what is the file name of html script you posted?  content-page.php or content.php

Comment: I posted two html scripts. The first is from my current theme,  I pulled that content by viewing page source in Chrome. I looked into both those folders and it isn't contained there. It seems to be contained in the archive.php. I'll add the code it seems to be in to the end of my post.

Comment: add condition  like `elseif ( is_homepage() || is_front_page() ) {`

Comment: did you display the post in template?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you're saying. I can add the condition to the code. Can you try to explain further, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think you should use `.page-title` instead of `#main`

```
.page-title, #reply-title {
    background-color: #dc2834;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Raleway",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    padding: 2px 0 1px 35px;
    position: relative;
}
.page-title a {
    color: #fff;
}
.page-title::before, #reply-title::before {
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid #000;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    bottom: -5px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.page-title::after, #reply-title::after {
    background: #dc2834 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.page-title, .page-title a, .page-title::after {  background-color: #000000;}
```

And in index.php file after

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
```

please add below code

```
<h1 class="page-title">Latest Posts</h1>
```

it is working fine. See https://ibb.co/nmhKVk

Comment: It doesn't appear that .page-title is a class in twentysixteen. I did a "Ctrl F" of the site page's source to verify. I can post further code if need be. In the meantime, I'll try to mess around to see if I can get any of the classes to fix the problem using your code.

Comment: Yeah, the code you posted didn't seem to work. I tried using #main with it, #primary, and .entry-header.

Comment: In which page you are going to implement this style?  It is working well on category post listing page, See below link.
https://ibb.co/h2UtO5

Comment: I am attempting to implement the style on the home page of my blog. It is the home page for the twenty sixteen template. Instead of a static front page, I would like to display latest posts, and I would like the latest posts to have a section title that reads "latest post" like you've done in that screenshot.

Comment: Hi Above style is enough and please add a small code to index.php file to include this latest post title. I'm editing my answer now

Comment: You are welcome, If this helped you please mark my answer as the best answer here :)